# A Chrome extensions to highlight 'name' and 'id' attributes for sharing links

Tags: chrome, html

When I want to share a link that "jumps" to a specific position in a page I can do it with the link + `#some_id`.

Example: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

In order to find the ID I open the Chrome Developer Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) and search for a `name` or `id` attribute.

Is there a Chrome extension that highlights `name` or `id` attributes so it will be quicker to find them?

Or maybe even with a 'copy' button that construct the link automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `2called-chaos`'s answer I came to this Chrome extension which works fine for now:

[Show Anchors](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/show-anchors/nhppnhnadikeniijclnghjfblnojgige/)

Comment: Even better :) The one I found is a bit rusty. Shows the links but the click action does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet (but will do now):

> Occasionally I want to link to specific section of a web page. Previously, I would bring up the source of the web page to see if there was a named anchor tag for the section in question, then I would manually add the anchor name as the URL fragment. Recently, however, I learned that any element with an ID attribute can act as a link target. It's only been stated in the HTML 4 specification like forever. :-)

http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/a-chrome-extension-for-easy-id-linking.html

Comment: Thanks! When I searched for LinkToId I came to the ShowAnchors extension. (Would vote up if I had the rep).